# Controlling layout of a checkbox in a custom Synth Look & Feel

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, look-and-feel, synth

I'm trying to implement a custom "Steampunk" themed look and feel using Synth - basically providing custom versions of SynthStyle, SynthPainter and SynthStyleFactory.

I am not using any XML, i.e. everything is done through the Java API. In general this is working just fine and actually starting to look pretty decent.

However I am having trouble with some "composite" components such as JCheckBox. When the paintCheckBoxBackground() is called on the SynthPainter the coordinates refer to the whole area covered by the JCheckBox.

How should I determine where in this region the check box icon and text separately need to be drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, mb the following will help
(the code is to put into your custom painter associated with JCheckBox):

```
public void paintCheckBoxBackground(SynthContext context, Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h){

    AbstractButton c = (AbstractButton) context.getComponent();
    String text = c.getText();
    Icon icon = c.getIcon();
    if (icon == null){
        icon = context.getStyle().getIcon(context, "CheckBox.icon");
    };        
    int iconTextGap = c.getIconTextGap();       

    Rectangle componentRect = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle iconR = new Rectangle();

    Insets insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (context.getRegion().isSubregion()){
        insets = context.getStyle().getInsets(context, insets);
    }
    else{
        insets = context.getComponent().getInsets(insets);
    }

    componentRect.x = insets.left;
    componentRect.y = insets.top;
    componentRect.width = c.getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
    componentRect.height = c.getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

    if (icon != null){
        iconR.x += componentRect.x;
        iconR.y += componentRect.y;
        iconR.width = icon.getIconWidth();
        iconR.height = icon.getIconHeight();

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(iconR.x, iconR.y, iconR.width, iconR.height);
    }
    if (text != null){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        int textPos = iconR.x + iconR.width + iconTextGap;
        g.fillRect(textPos, iconR.y, c.getWidth() - insets.right - textPos, componentRect.height);            
    }
}
```

Please, take into account, that here only the most common case is taken into account (Left-Right alignment, text right of the icon).
For more complex case treatment see source code for `SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel`

Comment: Thanks - this is very helpful example code! So basically the paintCheckBoxBackground code is responsible for painting both the text and the check mark icon?

Comment: @mikera For painting the background for them. UI Delegate (`SynthCheckBoxUI`, the text painting code is in `SynthButtonUI`,  `paint(SynthContext context, Graphics g)`) is painting text & icon themselves.